# How to filter query based on a field value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm working with elasticsearch Query dsl, and I can't find a way to express the following:

Return results that have the field `"price" > min budget` and have "price" < max Budget and have `has_price=true` and also return all results that have `"has_price=false"`

In other words, I would like to use a range filter on results only that have has_price field set to true, otherwise, on results that have has_price set to false don't take in consideration the filter

Here's the mapping:

```
{
  "formations": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "code": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dd/MM/yyyy"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "has_price": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "place": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show mapping of index?

Comment: @DejanMarić Alright, I just added it

Answer (score 0):

The following query combines the **2 scenarios** as **2 should clauses in a bool-query**. And as there are only should clauses, `minimum_should_match` will be 1, meaning that at least one should-clause has to match:

**Abstract Code Snippet**

```
GET formations/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { <1st scenario: has_price = false> },
        { <2nd scenario> has_price = true AND price IN budget_range}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Actual Sample Code Snippets**

```
# 1. Create the index and populate it with some sample documents

POST formations/_bulk
{"index": {"_id": 1}}
{"has_price": true, "price": 2.0}
{"index": {"_id": 2}}
{"has_price": true, "price": 3.0}
{"index": {"_id": 3}}
{"has_price": true, "price": 4.0}
{"index": {"_id": 4}}
{"has_price": false, "price": 2.0}
{"index": {"_id": 5}}
{"has_price": false, "price": 3.0}
{"index": {"_id": 6}}
{"has_price": false, "price": 4.0}

# 2. Query assuming min_budget = 2.0 and max_budget = 4.0

GET formations/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "has_price": false
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "has_price": true
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "price": {
                    "gt": 2,
                    "lt": 4
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

# 3. Result Snippet (4 hits: 3 from 1st scenario & 1 from 2nd scenario)
"hits" : {
  "total" : {
    "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    ...
```

Don't forget to add the Claus `"minimum_should_match": 1` to your bool-query in case you add another non-should-clause to your bool-query.

Let me know if this answers your question & solves your issue.